# Why do photos change color when you open an .odt file in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, compatibility, openoffice, photos

I have an .odt document (OpenOffice) containing photos. When I open the document with Microsoft Word, the photos are displayed darker then they were. Why is this the case?

I would like to be able to open the .odt document with Microsoft Word on a computer that does not have OpenOffice installed.

Comment: This sounds like a difference in gamma-correction. When you place a PNG version of an image next to a jpeg version of the same image in an ODT document, are they the same? Does the PNG then look the same in Word (when opening the same ODT), but the Jpeg not? PNG support embedded gamma correction AFAIK, the other formats do not. Default gamma can be different between software and especially OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution was to open the .odt file in WordPad and save it as .docx.

Comment: This could have big issues with formatting and you will still get the colour issue.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that .odt doesn't use the same colour chart as .doc, so when the file is opened Word does it's best to replicate the colour based on the nearest colour.

So long as they have Office set to open xml format files all Open Office files should be compatible.

Please see link:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-the-OpenDocument-Text-odt-format-and-the-Word-docx-format-d9d51a92-56d1-4794-8b68-5efb57aebfdc

Comment: Colour chart? Any palette would be part of the embedded image, and photos shouldn't use one. The only things that sound plausible here would be gamma correction and colour profile. And I'd doubt that the word processor actually changed the embedded image; it's probably just down to display in the application.